# Codeiginter Session Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem in a session
ihave made a login page called"alogin"

```
    <?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project    Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

class alogin extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('articles_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

}
function index(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username',' اسم المستخدم','trim|required|xxs_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','كلمة المرور','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->run();
    //post value
    $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
    $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');

    if($this->input->post('login')){

        if($this->user_model->login($data)){
            $this->setsession();



            redirect('admin/index');
        }  else {
            redirect('admin');
        }

    }
    $this->load->view('admin/login');
}


 public function setsession(){
    $dat = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
           'loggedIn' => TRUE
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($dat);
}

public function logout(){

     if($this->session->sess_destroy()){
         redirect('admin/alogin');
     }  else {
        // redirect('admin/log/index');
     }
}
}
```

and make the admin pages in controller file called"admin"
and this is the code

```
<?php 

class admin extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('articles_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
     if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){
        redirect('alogin');
    }


}

public function index(){
    $data['count'] =  $this->admin_model->count_message();
    $data['messages'] = $this->admin_model->show_message();
    $data['title']  = '  لوحة التحكم';
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/main';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);


}
public function setting(){



 $data['settings']=  $this->admin_model->settings();
 $data['title']  = ' تعديل اعدادات الموقع';
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/setting';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}
public function set_update(){
    $data = array(
        'site_name' => $this->input->post('site_name'),
        'site_desc'=> $this->input->post('site_desc')
    );
   $update = $this->admin_model->set_update($data);
   if(isset($update)){
       redirect('admin/setting');


   }
}
function message(){
    $data['messages'] = $this->admin_model->show_message();
        $data['title'] = 'الرسائل';
        $data['subview'] = 'admin/message';
        $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
    }


   /// articles
  public function add_article(){
  //
   // do upload 
     $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 3000;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 1000;
             $this->load->library('upload', $config);
             if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                 $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
             }  else {
                 $data['img_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                 $img = $this->upload->data();

             }



  $articels = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'content' =>  $this->input->post('content'),
    'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
    'img' => @$img['full_path'],
  );

if($this->input->post('add')){
  //form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','title','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('author','title','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('content','title','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('img','title','required');
       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('admin/add_c');
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->load->view('admin');
            }
    //form validation
    if($this->articles_model->add_article($articels)){
        $data['message'] = 'تم اضافة الخبر بنجاح';
    }

}  else {
    echo 'problem';
}
$data['title'] = 'اضافة خبر';
$data['subview'] = 'admin/add_c';
$this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
  }
    public function articles(){

    $data['articels'] = $this->articles_model->get_articles();
    $data['title']  = 'عرض المقالات';
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/articles';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
  }
   function delete_articels($id){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
   if( $this->articles_model->delete_articles($id)){
       redirect('admin/articles');
   }
}
        function edit_articels(){
            $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['articels'] = $this->articles_model->get_article_id($id);
            $artc = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
                'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
                'img'     => $this->input->post('img')
            );
            if($this->input->post('update')){
                if($this->articles_model->edit_c($id,$artc)){
                    echo 'تم تعديل المقال بنجاح';
                }  else {
                    echo 'مشكلة فى تعديل البيانات';
                }
            }

            $data['title'] = 'تعديل المقال';
            $data['subview'] = 'edit_c';
        $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);


}
public function stat(){

$data['stats']= $this->admin_model->get_static();
$data['subview'] = 'admin/stat';
 $data['title'] = 'تعديل احصائيات العيادة';
$this->load->view('admin/index',$data);

}

// pat 

function add_pat(){
    $pats = array(
        'pat_name' => $this->input->post('pat_name'),
        'pat_pat' => $this->input->post('pat_pat'),
        'pat_content'=> $this->input->post('pat_content')
    );
    if($this->input->post('add')){
        $this->admin_model->add_pat($pats);
    }


    $data['subview'] = 'admin/add_pat';
    $data['title'] ='اضافة حالة جديدة';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}
function show_pats(){

    $data['title'] = 'عرض الحالات ';
    $data['pats'] = $this->admin_model->show_pat();
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/show_pats';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}

function delete_pat(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if($this->admin_model->delete_pat($id)){
        redirect('admin/show_pats');
    }

}

function edit_pat(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $pat = array(
       'pat_name' => $this->input->post('pat_name'),
        'pat_pat' => $this->input->post('pat_pat'),
        'pat_content' => $this->input->post('pat_content')
    );
    if($this->input->post('update')){
        if($this->admin_model->edit_pat($id,$pat)){
             redirect('admin/show_pats');
             echo 'done';
        }  else {
            redirect('home');
        }

    }

    $data['title'] = 'تعديل';
    $data['pats'] = $this->admin_model->show_pat_id($id);
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/edit_pat';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}


/// videos

function show_videos(){
    $data['videos']= $this->admin_model->get_videos();
    $data['title'] = 'عرض الفديوهات';
    $data['subview'] ='admin/show_videos';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}

function add_video(){
    $add = array(
        'video_title' => $this->input->post('video_title'),
        'video_url' => $this->input->post('video_url')
    );
    if($this->input->post('add')){
        $this->admin_model->add_video($add);
        redirect('admin/show_videos');
    }
    $data['title'] = 'اضف فديو جديد ';
    $data['subview'] = 'admin/add_video';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}

function edit_video(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
     $data['videos'] = $this->admin_model->get_video_id($id);
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $edit = array(
        'video_title' => $this->input->post('video_title'),
        'video_url'=> $this->input->post('video_url')
    );
    if($this->input->post('update')){
        $this->admin_model->edit_video($id,$edit);
        redirect('admin/show_videos');
    }  else {
        echo 'problem';
    }
    $data['title'] = 'تعديل الفديو';

    $data['subview'] = 'admin/edit_video';
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);
}

function delete_video(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if($this->admin_model->delete_video($id)){
        redirect('admin/show_videos');
    }
}
}
```

the page is login successfuly but if i refresh or go to any inner admin page 
redirect to login page ???

```
Array
(
[__ci_last_regenerate] => 1442853634
[username] => nader
[password] => 01147187698
[loggedIn] => 1
)
```

and the problem is when i refresh the index page or enter any page redirect to alogin(login page)

Answer (score 0):

Try on your admin controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == FALSE){
        redirect('alogin');
    }

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('articles_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

}
```

And change on your session check ! to FALSE and move it to the top like shown

Also try and var dump sessions just to make sure working.

```
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the user session in constructor of each controller
in your controller where you are saving session ..?

first of all make a method in base/parent controller to check the user is login 
then call it in each controller's constructor

you can check all stored session through below given method

$this->session->all_userdata();

Comment: aslo you can initialize the session lib in auto load to avoid re-declared in each controller